# Как сформировать одномерный строчный массив (string) с перенесением информации в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Интересует вопрос, каким образом, после образования массива

```
string [] k = {"AB", "CD", "EF", ...}
```

Перенести значения в `DataGridView` в рандомном порядке (в одну строку) в Windows Form (C#).
При этом, можно ли в обратном порядке извлекать значения с `DataGridView` или правильнее будет снова обратиться за этим к массиву?

Спасибо

Comment: Очень странная задача, зачем в рандомном порядке?

Comment: Что касается рандомного порядка - вопрос основан исключительно на интересе.
Основная задача касается именно обратного вывода либо в том же DataGridView, либо в другом (относительно string массива).

Comment: Не вижу проблемы создать новый массив с перемешанными или реверснутыми значениями и работать с ним.